# Flink multi source with kafka, kinesis and TableEnvironment

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

I'm new to Flink and hope someone can help. I have tried to follow Flink tutorials.

We have a requirement where we consume from:

1. kafka topic.

When an event arrives on kafka topic we need the json event fields (mobile_acc_id, member_id, mobile_number, valid_from, valid_to) to be stored in an external db (Postgres db)

2. kinesis stream.

When an event arrives on kinesis stream we need to look up the mobile_number, on the event, in Postgres DB (from step 1) and extract the "member_id" from db and enrich the incoming kinesis event and sink it to another output stream

So I set up a Stream and a Table environment like this:

```
public static StreamExecutionEnvironment initEnv() {
    var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(0L); //disables watermark
    return env;
}

public static TableEnvironment initTableEnv() {
    var settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build();
    return TableEnvironment.create(settings);
}
```

calling process(..) methods with **initEnv()** will use kinesis as the source!

process(config.getTransformerConfig(), input, sink, deadLetterSink, **initEnv()**);

In the process(..) am also initialising the Table Environment using **initTableEnv()** hoping that Flink with consume from **both sources** when I call **env.execute(..)**:

```
public static void process(TransformerConfig cfg, SourceFunction<String> source, SinkFunction<UsageSummaryWithHeader> sink,
                           SinkFunction<DeadLetterEvent> deadLetterSink, StreamExecutionEnvironment env) throws Exception {
    var events =
            StreamUtils.source(source, env, "kinesis-events", cfg.getInputParallelism());

    collectInSink(transform(cfg, events, deadLetterSink), sink, "kinesis-summary-events", cfg.getOutputParallelism());

    processStreamIntoTable(initTableEnv());

    env.execute("my-flink-event-enricher-svc");
}

private static void processStreamIntoTable(TableEnvironment tableEnv) throws Exception {
    tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE mobile_accounts (\n" +
            "    mobile_acc_id VARCHAR(36)              NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    member_id     BIGINT                   NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    mobile_number        VARCHAR(14)              NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    valid_from    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    valid_to      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL \n" +
            ") WITH (\n" +
            "    'connector' = 'kafka',\n" +
            "    'topic'     = 'mobile_accounts',\n" +
            "    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',\n" +
            "    'format'    = 'json'\n" +
            ")");

    tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE mobile_account\n" +
            "(\n" +
            "    mobile_acc_id VARCHAR(36)              NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    member_id     BIGINT                   NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    mobile_number        VARCHAR(14)              NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    valid_from    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    valid_to      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL \n" +
            ") WITH (\n" +
            "   'connector'  = 'jdbc',\n" +
            "   'url'        = 'jdbc:postgresql://flinkpg:5432/flink-demo',\n" +
            "   'table-name' = 'mobile_account',\n" +
            "   'driver'     = 'org.postgresql.Driver',\n" +
            "   'username'   = 'flink-demo',\n" +
            "   'password'   = 'flink-demo'\n" +
            ")");

    Table mobileAccounts = tableEnv.from("mobile_accounts");

    report(mobileAccounts).executeInsert("mobile_account");
}

public static Table report(Table mobileAccounts) {
    return mobileAccounts.select(
            $("mobile_acc_id"),
            $("member_id"),
            $("mobile_number"),
            $("valid_from"),
            $("valid_to"));
}
```

What I have noticed on the flink console is that it is only consuming from one Source!

I liked TableEnvironment as not much code is needed to get the items inserted into the DB.

How can we consume from both the sources, Kinesis and TableEnvironment in Flink?

Am I using the right approach?

Is there an alternative to implement my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are able to create the tables correct, then you can simply `JOIN` two streams named `kafka_stream` and `kinesis_stream` as

```
SELECT l.*, r.something_useful FROM kinesis_stream as l
INNER JOIN kafka_stream as r
ON l.member_id = r.member_id;
```

If PostgreSQL sink is essential, you can make it in a different query as

```
INSERT INTO postgre_sink
SELECT * FROM kafka_stream;
```

They will solve your problem with Table API (or Flink SQL).

Comment: So are suggesting using StreamExecutionEnvironment to consume from kafka and kinesis and not use TableEnvironment? If so, then I think, as you say, I can use Table API to do INSERTS and SELECTS.

Comment: Actually, you can convert Datastream to Table as https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/ . However, my point is, you can use a `JOIN`to enrich your stream.

Comment: The data in both streams are different. We don't want to join the streams on the fly. What we want is to store the data in Kafka topic into the DB and when an event arrives on Kinesis stream we want to look up the value in the DB and enrich the Kinesis event with the value from the matching DB reacord.

Comment: I ended up using the StreamExecutionEnvironment to consume from Kafka and Kinesis and then using the Table API, as mentioned by @Metehan. Thanks